# not getting how to forward 404 page when exception occured

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, exception, arithmeticexception

I am trying to handle ArithmeticException in servlet, catch block is
being execute but not forwarding to error page.

I am getting `ArithmeticException: / by zero`.
Can someone tell why it's not forwarded to `general-errorpage.jsp`

**web.xml**

```
<error-page>
<exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
<location>/ErrorHandler</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
<location>/general-errorpage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

**Servlet :**

```
@WebServlet("/ErrorHandler")
public class Abc extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {

int a=1,b=0,c=0; 

Throwable throwable = (Throwable) 
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
     String servletName = (String) 
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.servlet_name");

try{    
    c= a/b;
}
catch(ArithmeticException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();           

            request.setAttribute("error", "Servlet " + servletName + 
                " has thrown an exception " + throwable.getClass().getName() 
 +
                " : " + throwable.getMessage() );    
              request.getRequestDispatcher("/general-
 errorpage.jsp").forward(request, response);


    }

 }
```

**Error page is :**

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" import="java.io.*" contentType="text/html" %> 
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Error Page -  </title>
</head>
<body> 


<table><tr><td>${statusCode}</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use error.jsp in <location> tag

Comment: @sForSujit, I am using <location>/general-errorpage.jsp</location>, is that a problem?

Comment: tell me what is ErrorHandler in your web.xml?

Comment: @sForSujit, for every status code I used ErrorHandler to forward to general-error.jsp, am I wrong?

Comment: you cannot do like that, you will need to provide location in same <error-page> tag

Comment: change doPost method to doGet method.

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt, I have updated to doGet but this not solved my problem

Comment: @sForSujit, I updated my web.xml please check once

Comment: Try throwing exception from another servlet, then container invoke ErrorHandler servlet with status code. Get status code using .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code"); and forward. And remove part of /general-errorpage.jsp in web.xml.

Comment: Can you tell me, how are you executing this project?

Comment: @sForSujit, by exporting war file into JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA server

Comment: And how are you calling the Abc class? & that doGet Method?

Comment: @sForSujit, asdf.jsp is my jsp and action page is Abc.java, I have give Abc.java code and general-errorpage.jsp code above.

Comment: @BharathPateru see the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is here: The code you wrote in web.xml will not even compile because whenever you are using `<error-page>`, you must have `<exception-type>` or `<exception-code>` tag along with it.

```
<error-page>
     <location>/general-errorpage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

So please make changes in your web.xml. By using this you can handle the exception of any type : (You can also keep the exception type to java.lang.Throwable)

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/general-errorpage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

I would like to add some more, If you wanted to handle the exception for the specific error code, then you can do something like this :

```
<error-page>  
    <error-code>500</error-code>  
    <location>/general-errorpage.jsp</location> 
</error-page>
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: thanks it's worked like a charm, but how do I get exeption message,code printed in general-error.jsp page

Comment: I am glad you got your mistake, and You mean you wanted to show the exception code on error page?

Comment: Will tell you, just give me 5-10 mins

Comment: I am not sure, how to get the error code of particular exception